# Using Nagios with the new FIWARE Monitoring component

Tags: fiware, fiware-monitoring

I'm already using Nagios in my infrastructure to get monitoring information about my OpenStack instance and the different resources deployed on it. How could I integrate it into new FIWARE Monitoring architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new architecture you mention is based on OpenStack [Monasca](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Monasca). Metrics are collected by the so-called [Monasca Agents](https://github.com/openstack/monasca-agent/blob/master/docs/Agent.md#architecture) deployed at the infrastructures being monitored.

Although FIWARE Monitoring GE configures Monasca to retrieve data from **OpenStack Ceilometer** service, Monasca Agents include **plugins** as extension mechanism in order to gather monitoring information from other sources. [Here](https://github.com/openstack/monasca-agent/blob/master/docs/Plugins.md#nagios-checks) you will find details about the configuration of Agents to execute Nagios Plugins.